# Extracting array data

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a script that will grab domain names from a webpage and print a list of ones that match certain criteria.

I have the data in an array but I can't seem to print it out in a friendly format although no matter what I try I cannot seem to extract what I need.

An example of my array is shown below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => domain1.com.au
            [1] => domain2.com.au
            [2] => domain3.com.au
            [3] => domain4.com.au
            [4] => domain5.com.au
        )

)
```

Basically I just want to print each occurrence of *.com.au on a new line.

If someone to give me an example or suggestion it would be great.

Comment: also, please sanitize as Mihai sayd, before storing values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($array[0] as $domain){
    if(strstr($domain, '.com.au')){
        echo $domain."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted, I also like that you included sanitation as there is a possibility that stray data will find itself into the array.

Answer (score 2):

The array you supplied should be in `$array`.

`PHP_EOL` inserts a newline if you look at the source. `<br />` inserts a new line visually

```
foreach ($array[0] as $domain){
    echo $domain.'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
foreach( $arr[0] as $key => $value)
{
echo '<br/>'. $value;
}
```